# Finding percentage of points within tilted ellipse?

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, fitting, counting

I am trying to find the number of data points that I have that are within a tilted ellipse that I have generated to represent the 68% confidence region. I generated some data using:

```
y[a_,b_,x_] := a + b*x
sigma = 0.1;
xi = Table[i,{i,10}];
len = Length[xi];
nSim = 10^3;
simSets = Table[Table[{xi[[i]],RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[y[1,0.5,xi[[i]]],sigma]]},{i,len}],nSim];
yDat = Table[Table[simSets[[j,i,2]],{i,len}],{j,nSim}];
```

Then I found the $\chi^2$ for every simulated data set like so:

```
firstDeg[a_,b_,x_] := a + b*x
chiSq[a_,b_] = Table[Sum[(firstDeg[a,b,xi[[i]]]-yDat[[j,i]])^2/sigma^2,{i,len}],{j,nSim}];
mins = Table[FindMinimum[chiSq[a,b][[i]],{{a,1},{b,0.5}}],{i,nSim}];
```

For the $a$ and $b$ values, I collected the values that minimized the $\chi^2$:

```
listA = Table[a/.mins[[j,2,1]],{j,nSim}];
listB = Table[b/.mins[[j,2,2]],{j,nSim}];
```

and then tried finding the 68% confidence region by using the fact that the semi-major and minor axis are $\sqrt{2.3}\sigma_a,\sqrt{2.3}\sigma_b$

**EDIT:** $\sigma_a,\sigma_b$ found via:

```
VarA = Total[(listA-Mean[listA])^2]/Length[listA];
VarB = Total[(listB-Mean[listB])^2]/Length[listB];
sigmaA = Sqrt@VarA;
sigmaB = Sqrt@VarB;
```

and the orientation of the ellipse via $\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac{v_1(b)}{v_1(a)}\right)$, where $v_1$ refers to the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.
I calculate the region for the parameters like so:

```
axes[delchisq_,sig_] := sig*Sqrt[delchisq]
paramVal = Table[{a,b}/.nlm[[j]]["BestFitParameters"],{j,nSim}];
paramValM = Mean@paramVal;
angle[covariance_] := ArcTan[Eigenvectors[covariance][[1,2]]/Eigenvectors[covariance][[1,1]]]

aUp = paramValM[[1]]+axes[2.3,sigmaA]
aLow = paramValM[[1]]-axes[2.3,sigmaA]
bUp = paramValM[[2]]+axes[2.3,sigmaB]
bLow = paramValM[[2]]-axes[2.3,sigmaB]
valIn = Table[If[(paramVal[[i,1]] >= aLow \[And] paramVal[[i,1]] <= aUp)\[And](paramVal[[i,2]] >= bLow \[And] paramVal[[i,2]] <= bUp),paramVal[[i]],Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],{i,Length@paramVal}];
Print["The percentage of (a,b) points within the 68% confidence region is ",N@(Length@valIn/nSim)*100,"%."]
(* The percentage of (a,b) points within the 68% confidence region is 83.9%. *)
```

and then I plot (I also calculated the covariance matrix "by hand", as it were, and that is to what covMat refers):

```
p68 = Graphics[Rotate[Circle[paramValM,{axes[2.3,sigmaA],axes[2.3,sigmaB]}],angle[covMat]],Frame->True];
valPt = Graphics[{Directive[Red],PointSize[Medium],Point[valIn]},Frame->True];
Show[p68,valPt]
```

[image: scatter plot with tilted ellipse]
Obviously, I'm not counting the points in the ellipse correctly, but beside that, I'm not counting many points outside of the ellipse, and yet I'm getting that 83.9% of my $(a,b)$ points are in the region. Why would that be?

Any help in correctly 1) calculating the 68% confidence region (I'd prefer not to use ["ParameterConfidenceRegion", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.68]), and 2) finding the points within the tilted ellipse would be a great help.

Comment: Can you give the values of sigmaA and sigmaB used above?

Comment: @SHuisman oh sure, it's been edited in. I think it would be about what one would expect, though? Maybe I'm wrong tho

Comment: Have you considered using `BinormalDistribution`?

Comment: @kirma Could you explain what you mean by that? I don't immediately see the application here.